# Targeting closest element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a open/close button absolute positioned on top of an image. It works fine except when i click to toggle the class it targets all images

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
      <li>
         <span class="minMax"></span>
         <img>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span class="minMax"></span>
         <img>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**jQuery** current code

```
$('.minMax').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $('img ').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

i have tried using `.closest()` but it wont work

```
   $('.minMax').click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
      $(this).closest('img').toggleClass('expanded');
    });
```

any idea on how to target the image that the span is layered on?

Comment: That's obviously not what `.closest` is documented to do.

Comment: why all the minuses, im having trouble targeting a single image did i not ask this properly

Comment: You asked without consulting the documentation.

Comment: `.closest()` goes up the parents till it finds the selector provided. You would use it, then find the image inside the element it returns.

Comment: @kevin B thank you for all the 'constructive' comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `siblings()` function :

```
$('.minMax').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $(this).siblings('img').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

You can also go back to your parent and find img children, imo the proper and logical way to do it :

```
$('.minMax').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
  $(this).parent().find('img').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.next()`

```
$(this).next('img').toggleClass('expanded');
```

Comment: As for why `.closest()` doesn't work: "For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing _up through its ancestors_ in the DOM tree." (emphasis mine).

Comment: when i add next() or closest() or find() the class doesnt get applied to the image just the span

Comment: @JMcFee of course it doesn't... because you're now targeting the span instead.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
$(this).parent().find('img').toggleClass('expanded');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use on() having in mind event delegation, in case you add new items in the list.

Here's an example: [(**Example**)](http://jsfiddle.net/DfduB/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.minMax', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    $(this).parent().find('img').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```